# Fix undefined index

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am constantly getting "Notice: Undefined index: ..." I think I know why I just don't know how to fix it. I have a html form page with all of this "if" statements that only display messages to the user when needed. I included this html page on a controller php page that has $_SESSION variables which get variables from my backend php script that handles database manipulation.

So to make it easier to understand here is the flow of my logic for the page I am building: HTML(form page sends data to) ---> PHP (page that handles database etc.. and then redirects the user to) ---> PHP (controller page that displays the data to users, html page is included here) ---> HTML(original page with form now displays correct data to user)

But whenever if or else statement in html isn't achieved I get a notice about undefined index for that variable... Below is my html and controller php page. Let's say that `if(!$_POST and $poskodbe != '0')` statement is fulfilled because nobody clicked submit button, fine everything is okay but I get the notice for my second `else if ($poskodbe == '0'){text($moznost);` which reads "Notice: Undefined index: moznost". Why?

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
    <?php if(!$_POST and $poskodbe != '0') { ?>
    <p>Presenetil<?php text($spol); ?> te je <?php text($monster); ?> !</p>
<form action='../php/gozd.php' method='post'>
    <input type='submit' name='action' value='Napadi' /> ali 
    <input type='submit' name='action' value='Pobegni' />
            <input type='hidden' name='monster' value= '<?php text($monster); ?>' />
</form>
    <?php } 

    else if ($poskodbe == '0'){text($moznost); ?> 
    <p><a href='../php/start.php'>Odpravi se proti domu</a></p> 
    <?php } 

    else { ?>        
    <ul><?php foreach ($combat as $turns => $i) { ?>
        <li> <p><strong><?php text($i['napadalec']); ?></strong>
             <?php text(' napade '); ?><strong><?php text($i['branilec']); ?></strong>
             <?php text(' in mu napravi poškodbe za ') ?><strong><?php text($i['damage']); ?></strong>
             <?php text(' točk zdravja '); } ?> </p></li> 
    </ul>

    <?php if(isset ($zmaga)) { ?> 
    <p>Pregnal si <strong><?php text($monster_ime); ?></strong>! 
       V naglici je za seboj pustil <strong><?php text($cekini); ?></strong> cekinov, ki jih seveda pobereš.</p>
    <p><a href='../php/gozd.php'>Raziskuj dalje</a></p>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php if(isset ($zguba)) { ?>
    <p>Podlegel si poškodbam <strong><?php text($monster_ime); ?></strong>.</p>
    <?php } ?>

    <p><a href='../php/start.php'>Odpravi se proti domu</a></p>
    <?php } ?>        

</body>

</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

session_start();
include 'razno.php';
include 'stats.php';

$monster = $_SESSION['monster'];
$spol = $_SESSION['spol'];
$poskodbe = $_SESSION['poskodbe'];
$moznost = $_SESSION['moznost'];
$combat = $_SESSION['combat'];
$turns = $_SESSION['poskodbe'];

include '../html/gozd.html';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You get `Notice: Undefined index:` when you're accessing an array key that isn't set.

Considering your header script, I think that's where you're getting the notice.

You could try to avoid it like this:

```
$moznost = isset($_SESSION['moznost']) ? $_SESSION['moznost'] : -1;
```

Here if `moznost` is not set, you will get `-1`.

---

*Just a side note:*
It's not a good practice to combine English and Slovenian (if I guessed it right).
You'll do best if you keep all the code in English, translating only what is actually visible to the user.

Comment: Yeah its slovenian, thanks for the answer. I get the notice for my controller php yeah. Care to explain why? My variable is set though in my main php which adds data to $moznost ... Or atleast I think it is, what do you mean with "set" anyway?

Comment: Well, if there isn't a `'moznost'` key in your `$_SESSION`, you get this notice. You can try to track where exactly the notice is by adding few `echo`'s into the code. You can for example put `echo 'afterSessionRead';` right before `include '../html/gozd.html';` - that way, you will see *where exactly* the notice occurred.

Comment: Actually it can happen in any of your arrays, so you should also check if `$i['napadalec']` and similar thigns aren't the cause of your notice.

Comment: Well echo 'afterSessionRead'; just echoes "afterSessionRead". You said "Well, if there isn't a 'moznost' key in your $_SESSION, you get this notice" what do you mean? There is that key in my session, you can see it yourself...

Comment: What I see is that you do `$moznost = $_SESSION['moznost'];`. $_SESSION is just an array, despite it's special function. If you didn't assign anything to $_SESSION['moznost'] before, then you will get 'undefined index'. But I'm not sure it is in the session, it can be in any place where you read an array. You really should try to find the exact place using the notice message, it tells you on what row in which file the problem happened.

Comment: But I set my moznost in other php file and store it in session like so:

      if ($poskodbe == '0') {$_SESSION['moznost'] = ($moznost = 'Tvoje zdravje je resno ogroženo, vrni se domov!');}

Comment: Yes, I do not insist on the session causing the notice. It was only an idea. Since the notice tells you where it happened, it is not hard to find the place in your code that needs fixing.

Comment: I get you @MightyPork, awesome name btw :), though I don't know how to check that

Comment: putting isset in front of the ($_SESSION['moznost']) fixed my notice though. Don't know why.... Do you know?

Comment: That's impossible for me to know without having access to the actual files. If you fixed it, good.

Comment: actually it didn't fix it, now my variable just returns number 1 when echoing. Argh this is so annoying.. How do I track my error down

Comment: When I debug php, I put testing echos everywhere and narrow down the buggy area, and then find and fix what's broken. I don't think there are many other ways.

Comment: Sorry I am a bit of a newby and don't understand what do you mean with putting testing echoes everywhere

Comment: The thing is once the if statement in my html has been fulfilled I don't get the error anymore even if I refresh my page and the if statement is not fulfilled anymore. Until I log out and close my session, then its the same thing all over again. So I assume the problem is in session somewhere not remembering the values correctly

Comment: Looks like when I put $_SESSION['moznost'] = $moznost outside of my if statement in my backend php file, error is gone. So I guess I was receiving the error because $moznost really wasn't set in my controller php, because the if statement wasn't activated in my backend php

Comment: really hard to know without seeing all the code, I guess I'll just leave you to this